# Dealing with white spaces in attribute names in ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr2ogr, syntax

I am trying to convert a sub-set of my geodatabase into a shapefile using `ogr2ogr`. The problem is that both the attribute name and the value have spaces, so when I use sql to subset it gives me syntax errors. My attempts are

```
ogr2ogr -where "bad attribute title = bad attribute value" -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.gdb
```

failed!

```
ogr2ogr -where "[bad attribute title] = [bad attribute value]" -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.gdb
```

failed!

```
ogr2ogr -where "`bad attribute title` = `bad attribute value`" -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.gdb
```

failed!

```
ogr2ogr -where ""bad attribute title" = "bad attribute value"" -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.gdb
```

failed!

What's the correct way to do this? I can't make the changes in the gdb file as it's huge with a lot of similar columns.

Comment: `"\"bad attribute title\" = \"bad attribute value\""`

Comment: I think it worked. But I am getting a different error `"bad attribute title" not recognised as an available field.`I don't think it has anything to do with the spaces. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: It says that your layer does not have a field named "bad attribute title". Do you think that you have? Check the names of the fields that GDAL finds with `ogrinfo  input.gdb -so`. You did not select any layer, do you have only one in the gdb?

Comment: Yeah, it's just one layer and I double-checked the attribute name with qgis. `ogrinfo  input.gdb -so` also shows one layer - but it doesn't show the attribute details. I imported part of this gdb to postgis using ogr2ogr which shows the name as `bad_attribute_title`. I am a bit confused. Does importing gdb into postgis changes attribute titles? Is there a way to check the attribute titles and the list of attribute values using ogr in the terminal?

Comment: Sorry, you must run `ogrinfo -al -so input.gdb`. PostGIS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html probably launders the names to use underscores. Instead of `-where` you can use explicit SQL `-sql "select * from my_layer where \"bad attribute title\"=\"bad attribute value\"" input.gdb`.

Comment: Okay. I can see all the attributes have alternative names. And they are completely different - not just underscores. I tried with the alternative name for the "bad attribute title" and I don't see that error message anymore. But now I have a similar error message for the value - `"bad attribute value" not recognized as an available field`. Does this mean the they also have alternative names? I wish there is a way to do this in a loop for all the attribute values without using sql at all.

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid SQL error. It must be `-sql "select * from my_layer where \"bad attribute title\"='bad attribute value'"`.

Comment: Great. This worked. Although I don't fully understand why it works. Would you mind explaining this a little? If you could please do this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: `bad attribute value` is a character string and in SQL strings must appear between single quotes. All strings, even `bad`. And there is nothing bad in your string. `bad attribute title` is field name, in SQL language "identifier", and because of spaces it is so called quoted identifier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468337/oracle-sql-syntax-quoted-identifier and it must be used between double quotes. And in the GDAL command line those double quotes that appear in between the double quates that belong to the command must be escaped with `\\` so that the parameter is not cut too early.

Comment: Please write the answer yourself and earn some credits.